# How to auto display form Update in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, loops

A part of a system I am creating has a kitchen display system but I dont get how to automatically display the contents in my form

```
 Public Sub GetOrders()

        Try

            kitchenFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Clear()

            Dim i As Integer
            Dim sql As String

            sql = "SELECT c.cart_id, c.invoice_no, c.table_no, c.sale_time, f.item_name, c.serve_size, c.quantity FROM tbl_cart AS c INNER JOIN tbl_food AS f on f.item_id = c.items_id WHERE c.status='Pending'"

            conn.Open()
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.ExecuteReader()
            conn.Close()

            Dim dTable1 As New DataTable()
            Dim dAdaptor1 As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            dAdaptor1.Fill(dTable1)

            Dim panel1 As FlowLayoutPanel
            Dim panel2 As FlowLayoutPanel

            For i = 0 To dTable1.Rows.Count - 1

                panel1 = New FlowLayoutPanel
                panel1.AutoSize = True
                panel1.Width = 260
                panel1.Height = 500
                panel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown
                panel1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                panel1.Margin = New Padding(10, 10, 10, 10)

                panel2 = New FlowLayoutPanel
                panel2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 55, 89)
                panel2.AutoSize = True
                panel2.Width = 230
                panel2.Height = 125
                panel2.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown
                panel2.Margin = New Padding(0, 0, 0, 0)

                Dim label1 As New Label
                label1.ForeColor = Color.White
                label1.Margin = New Padding(10, 5, 3, 0)
                label1.Font = New Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
                label1.AutoSize = True

                Dim label2 As New Label
                label2.ForeColor = Color.White
                label2.Margin = New Padding(10, 5, 3, 0)
                label2.AutoSize = True

                Dim label3 As New Label
                label3.ForeColor = Color.White
                label3.Margin = New Padding(10, 5, 3, 0)
                label3.AutoSize = True

                Dim label4 As New Label
                label4.ForeColor = Color.White
                label4.Margin = New Padding(10, 5, 3, 0)
                label4.AutoSize = True

                Dim label5 As New Label
                label5.ForeColor = Color.White
                label5.Margin = New Padding(10, 5, 3, 0)
                label5.AutoSize = True

                label1.Text = "Entry ID   : " & dTable1.Rows(i)("cart_id").ToString
                label2.Text = "Invoice No : " & dTable1.Rows(i)("invoice_no").ToString
                label3.Text = "Table No   : " & dTable1.Rows(i)("table_no").ToString
                label4.Text = "Order Time : " & dTable1.Rows(i)("sale_time").ToString
                label5.Text = Environment.NewLine & "ORDERED ITEM : " & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & " Item : " & dTable1.Rows(i)("item_name").ToString & Environment.NewLine & " Serve Size : " & dTable1.Rows(i)("serve_size").ToString & Environment.NewLine & " Qty: " & dTable1.Rows(i)("quantity").ToString & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine

                panel2.Controls.Add(label1)
                panel2.Controls.Add(label2)
                panel2.Controls.Add(label3)
                panel2.Controls.Add(label4)
                panel2.Controls.Add(label5)

                panel1.Controls.Add(panel2)

                Dim btn As New Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2Button

                btn.AutoRoundedCorners = True
                btn.Size = New Size(100, 35)
                btn.FillColor = Color.FromArgb(241, 85, 126)
                btn.Margin = New Padding(60, 5, 3, 10)
                btn.Location = New Point(0, 0)
                btn.Text = "Complete"
                btn.Tag = dTable1.Rows(i)("cart_id").ToString ' store id 

                AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btn_Click

                panel2.Controls.Add(btn)

                kitchenFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(panel1)

            Next

        Catch ex As Exception

            conn.Close()
            MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)

        End Try

    End Sub
```

I tried putting it in a do loop but it shows errors even before I can log in to the system.

I have also tried to use incorporate "GetOrders().refresh" but it was also not working.

[image]

Comment: `GetOrders` is a `Sub`, which means it doesn;t return anything, so why would you think you could call `Refresh` on what it returns? What do you think you're calling `Refresh` on?

Comment: can you advise on other means to refresh this sub sir?

Comment: You say that you tried a `Do` loop and got errors but there's no such loop or error messages in your question. There is code with a `For` loop but no mention of what that code actually does. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a proper question.

Comment: You don't "refresh a sub". If you want to execute the code in the method, you call the method.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve.

In this example, a button named RefreshButton was added to the Form.

This shows your GetOrders method getting called from the ButtonClick event.

```
   Private Sub GetOrders()

        'your GetOrders code...

    End Sub


    Private Sub RefreshButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RefreshButton.Click
        Try
            GetOrders() ' this will call your GetOrders method
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
        End Try
    End Sub
```